# Use rsync to create backup on remote Mac machine

Tags: macos, cocoa, rsync

I'm trying to use [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/) to create backup of my Mac machine on remote Mac machine. I have created key for ssh and copied it on remote machine as explained at: https://blogs.oracle.com/jkini/entry/how_to_scp_scp_and. But when I run the command: 
rsync -avz /Users/testuser/Desktop/test/ hostuser@192.168.50.94:/Users/hostuser/Desktop/test
 its showing:
    ssh: connect to host 192.168.50.94 port 22: Connection refused
    rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
    rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-40/rsync/io.c(452)     [sender=2.6.9] 

 
 Any idea how can I establish connection to remote machine to transfer files on remote machine from local machine???
**EDIT:**
I have to use it in my Cocoa application for mac.

Comment: This is not programming related. Voting to move to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH is disabled on Mac by default.

To enable it navigate to System Preferences > Sharing > enable "Remote Login" > "Allow access for" the users you want.

Then try again.

Comment: Thanks @Sun Liwen. Its working now. Sorry I have not mentioned above that I have to use it in my cocoa application. So can u tell me how can I do this with my Cocoa application??

Comment: @AmrinderSingh maybe you can try NSTask to wrap around the rsync command.

Comment: I'm asking to enable SSH on "Remote Machine" using my Cocoa application. Is there any command which can enable SSH on remote machine??

Comment: I found command to enable "Remote Login" and command is "systemsetup -setremotelogin On". This command enables Remote Login but gives message: "service: This command still works, but it is deprecated. Please use launchctl(8) instead.". Also when running command "systemsetup -setremotelogin Off", it asking yes/no to disable Remote Login. Is there any method which can disable Remote Login without asking yes/no??

Comment: @AmrinderSingh you can try $ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist

Comment: thanks for your help. But this command is asking for password and I have to enable remote login without asking password.

Comment: @AmrinderSingh IMO, you can't do that without authentication of the remote server. You might check key based authentication. In this way you don't have to type the password each time.